# Unable to receive array elements passed in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, urldecode, post-redirect-get

I am trying to send an array from one PHP file in the following manner:

```
$question_records=findQuestions($db,$student_id,$story_id,$call_number);
                echo count($question_records).'<br/>';
                $i=0;
                foreach($question_records as $record=>$question)
                {
                    $questions_file[$i]=$question['file_name'].'_'.$question['concept_tested'];
                    $questions_id[$i]=$question['question_id'];
                    echo "Array Elements:</br>";
                                    echo $questions_file[$i]. "</br>";
                    $i++;
                }
```

**Output:**

```
Array Elements:
q1_comp
q2_vocab
q3_cri
```

**Function makeCall**

```
makeCall($call_id,$phone,$questions_file,$questions_id,$student_id,$story,$call_number);

    function makeCall($call_id,$phone,$questions_file,$questions_id,$student_id,$story,$call_number){
        $questions_file= urldecode(http_build_query($questions_file));
                echo "ECHO NEW STMT questions_file \n";
                echo $questions_file;
                $questions_id= urldecode(http_build_query($questions_id));
                echo "ECHO NEW STMT questions_id \n";
                echo $questions_id;
    }
    $url = $server.'/startCall.php?call_id='.$call_id.'&phone='.$phone.'&questions_id='.$questions_id.'&questions_file='.$questions_file.'&student_id='.$student_id.'&story='
                .$story.'&call_number='.$call_number.'&question_number=0&response=0&count_english=0&count_hindi=0';
    echo '<Redirect method="GET">startCall.php?'.$url.'</Redirect>';
```

**startCall.php**

```
    $questions_id=array('questions_id' => $_REQUEST['questions_id']); 
    $questions_file=array('questions_file' =>$_REQUEST['questions_file']);
    echo "FOR QUESTIONS ID in STARTCALL.PHP";
    echo 'output1'.$questions_file.'</br>';
    echo 'output2'.$questions_file[0];
```

The output I am getting is

```
output1Array
output2
```

However, what I want to be able to do is to access the array elements (q1_comp, q2_vocab, q3_cri). Does anyone know why it isn't working. I have tried everything and really need this to work asap. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenAsraf ChenAsraf maybe u can help

Comment: You have an unclosed quote here `echo 'output1'.$questions_file.'</br>` <-

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo..just edited my question @ICanHasCheezburger

Comment: I think you can't echo array directly try var_dump() or print_r(), U trying echo array in Output1 and trying echo undefined key [0] in output2, actualy u defined key as 'questions_file' in outoput2

Answer (score 0):

Try following in startCall.php

```
echo 'output1'.print_r($questions_file,true).'</br>';
```